# How to link 2 categories (Sync)

Tags: categories, plugin-recommendation, plugin-polylang

I want that whenever a user post something in category "Foo", the same content must be duplicated to the category "Bar" automatically. Is there such a plugin that automate the process? Or some PHP snippet? I have many categories.

Those categories are not the normal WordPress categories, they are custom, for a specific theme, like WooCommerce categories for example. So the plugin must support taxonomies.

The reason is I have a multi-language website, using Polylang plugin, it's user-generated content, most often the content is the same in both languages so it must be the same in both categories. When it's not the case, only then the admin would translate by hand.

The user inserts content always in the English category say "Home category", it must be duplicated automatically to "Casa" category in Spanish, for example.

Note that the second language is Arabic, the first is English, for every English category, there's an equivalent Arabic category, every English post must be inserted in the equivalent Arabic category.

Comment: can't you select both categories when creating the post?

Comment: @inarilo no polylang doesn't allow it, plus I need an automated way

Comment: hi, can you tell me what error you are getting with the code in my answer?

Comment: @inarilo 500 internal server error, i guess it's not your fault, i guess classipress categories insert different stuff into different table, what I'm asking for might be impossible without seeing how classipress creates categories

Comment: @inarilo coz it's classipress categories, not normal wp categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in your theme functions:

```
function mysite_clone_post($post_id, $post, $update) {
  if(!$update && in_category('home cat', $post)) {  //not handled updates and will only run if in this category
      $post_fields = array(  'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_content',
                             'post_content_filtered', 'post_title', 'post_excerpt', 'post_status', 'post_type',
                             'comment_status', 'ping_status', 'post_password', 'post_name', 'to_ping',
                             'pinged', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'post_parent', 'menu_order',
                             'post_mime_type', 'guid', 'tax_input', 'meta_input');
      $postarr = array();
      foreach($post as $k => $v) if(in_array($k, $post_fields)) $postarr[$k] = $v;            

      $postarr['ID']            = 0;
      $postarr['post_category'] = array('casa cat');
      //not handled post_parent          

      wp_insert_post($postarr);  //not handled errors - returns false on error   
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'mysite_clone_post', 10, 3);
```

As mentioned in the comments in the code, I have only handled new posts without post parents, and left out error handling.

I am also assuming there are only two categories and simply assigning the opposite one.

UPDATE:

For custom post types and taxonomies use the following:

```
function mysite_clone_post($post_id, $post, $update) {
  if(!$update && $post->post_type == 'myposttype' && has_term('home cat name, id or slug', 'mytaxonomy', $post)) {  //not handled updates and will only run if it is this custom post type and in this custom category
      $post_fields = array(  'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_content',
                             'post_content_filtered', 'post_title', 'post_excerpt', 'post_status', 'post_type',
                             'comment_status', 'ping_status', 'post_password', 'post_name', 'to_ping',
                             'pinged', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'post_parent', 'menu_order',
                             'post_mime_type', 'guid', 'tax_input', 'meta_input');
      $postarr = array();
      foreach($post as $k => $v) if(in_array($k, $post_fields)) $postarr[$k] = $v;            

      $postarr['ID']            = 0;          
      //not handled post_parent          

      if($newid = wp_insert_post($postarr)) {    //if saved successfully, add taxonomy, note that the value is assigned to $newid and not compared
          wp_set_object_terms($newid, 'desired cat id or slug', 'mytaxonomy');
      } else {
          //handle errors here
      }
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'mysite_clone_post', 10, 3);
```

In addition, to handle multiple category pairs, you could use an array but then you'd have to update it everytime you add a new category. I'd suggest naming (and using) the slugs in such a way that one can be easily derived from the other. So e.g. 'main_cat' and 'main_cat_ar'.

Then the first line would become:

```
if(!$update && $post->post_type == 'myposttype') {  //not handled updates and will only run if it is this custom post type
    $terms = get_the_terms($post, 'mytaxonomy');
    if(!is_array($terms) || count(explode('_ar', $terms[0]->slug)) > 1) return;    // if no terms were returned or it belongs to an arabic category, exit
```

and the line assigning the term to the new post becomes

```
wp_set_object_terms($newid, $terms[0]->slug.'_ar', 'mytaxonomy');
```

Comment: where to place that? functions.php?

Comment: yes, updated the answer, also changed the code a bit

Comment: one thing, $post has more properties than are accepted by wp_insert_post, I assume the extra fields will be ignored (by not being accessed) but if there is an error, you may want to just pick up the values you know you need from $post.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2gY2XSTT thats my theme function.php, i'm thinking to do it in ` $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->cp_ad_geocodes, array)`. Also I have many categories, each one have it's equivalent in the other language so perhaps ` if($postarr['post_category'] == in_category('home cat', $post_id))`

Comment: also my 2nd language is arabic, so i just need to copy the arabic string of the category right?

Comment: yes, copying the string should work, if you have many categories, maybe you could have a parent category for each language or if there is no easy way to map from language 1 cat to language 2 cat, use an array of category pairs against which to check. I don't understand what you mean by ", i'm thinking to do it in ` $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->cp_ad_geocodes, array)"

Comment: i meant that to insert the categories using that function rather than writing my own, if I write my own function as shown in your answer, where should I call it?

Comment: the last line attaches the function to the save_post action hook, so the function will be called everytime a post is saved.

Comment: if i put that function in `mytheme/include/functions.php` the website stops working and I get `500 internal server error`

Comment: checking, might be a syntax error

Comment: what does `10, 3` stand for in the last line?

Comment: I left the word array in the call to wp_insert_post. fixed it. 10 is the priority, functions added to this hook will be called in order of priority. 3 is the number of arguments.

Comment: when i click update post from admin area, i get same error now

Comment: after changing the code?

Comment: yes, before changing, the site wasn't working, now everything works but can't press update, i get an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60032/discussion-between-inarilo-and-lynob).

Comment: i left a comment in chat room